# How can I add the loop attribute to multiple audio tags

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am Javascript beginner. I have four audio tracks that are playing at the same time, and three buttons that controls the playback of these audios (Play, Stop and Pause) . I want to add a checkbox that, when checked, loops the 4 audios, and when unchecked, doesn't loop.

I've tried to make a function that, when the checkbox is checked, adds the loop attribute to the audio tags, but doesn't seems to work.

HTML:

```
<div id="multitrack__control-panel" class="multitrack__control-panel">
    <button id="pause" onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
    <button id="play" onclick="play()">Play</button>
    <button id="stop" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="loop" autocomplete="off" />
    
    <audio id="track1" class="stem" src="audio/track1.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="track2" class="stem" src="audio/track2.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="track3" class="stem" src="audio/track3.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="track4" class="stem" src="audio/track4.wav"></audio>
    <script src="js/multitrack.js"></script>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var audioElement = document.getElementsByClassName("stem");

for (var i=0; i<audioElement.length; i++) {
    audioElement[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            var _selector = document.querySelector('input[name=loop]');
            _selector.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
                if (_selector.checked) {
                    audioElement.loop = true;
                } else {
                    audioElement.loop = false;
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you registering a `DOMContentLoaded` listener inside a `click` listener?

Comment: also, you won't want to add the listener for the `loop` checkbox every time you click one of the audio elements - and, `audioElement.loop = true` is adding `loop` property to a `HTMLCollection`, not an actual element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be over-thinking this.

Register a single *change* event handler on the checkbox to toggle the `loop` property on your `<audio>` elements

```js
const audioElements = document.querySelectorAll("audio.stem");

document.querySelector("input[name=loop]")
  .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    audioElements.forEach((audio) => {
      audio.loop = e.target.checked;
    });
  });
```